# how can i secure my android app database data and network data?

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, security

i have an app that has about 20000 data . these data are locally is beside app in sqlite database. i couldn't place data on web because i using map and markers and i feel will be slow in processing. so i have to use local data instead of web.

how can i secure these data in android? additionally i have any web request to a webservice and web database for other works. how can secure sent or received data? i hear about sqlcipher but i don't know how does it encrypt and secure my data. if you can tell me about secure best practices please.....
with thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some ideas.

To secure android data in the SQLite database the only and best way is to ask the user to create a password. This password will be used to encrypt data before you store it in SQLite database. Thus if someone steals device they cannot even with root access read the data in SQLite database.

For web services use SSL certificates to encrypt data flowing up and down. This is a rather big topic though. If you are serious about this I would suggest buying a copy of this book called [Application Security for the Android Platform: Processes, Permissions, and Other Safeguards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449315070) .

Comment: thanks. but i can't understand  about password issue. what's your mea aout user? who is user? can you tell more clear? when i use password i use sql data and then move it to sqlite then use in my project . now where and when i should use password? thanks for book i reading it now. but not found good practices inside it.

Comment: Read the book completely as this is a rather big problem in android.  I will review the options later today and expand my answer

Comment: thanks i waiting for answer . i reading any issue of stackoverflow from any one that say use sqlcipher or use encryption or use password protect or... but each one of these solutions can not solve my problem of course i feel. i don't know use sqlcipher. password has problem in many issues. and encrpytion for 30000 data ? is it certainly(need big processes)? what should i do you think?